# SVG in-line editing works in Chrome not FF?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG file and I'd like the text to be editable. Following advice on stackoverflow, I'm using <foreignObject> to acheive this. (Code example below.)

It works a treat in the Chromium browsers, Chrome and Edge.
It doesn't work in IE, but then it doesn't support <foreignObject>, so no surprise.
It also doesn't work in Firefox and I can't figure out why.

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
        #text2edit {
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:24px;
        }
    </style>
    <path id="screen" d="M0 0h300v100H0z" fill="#00f"/>
    <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="280" height="50">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" contenteditable="true" id="text2edit"
 style="color: #d4defb; background-color:#000;text-align: center;">Click to edit</div>
    </foreignObject>
    <text width="300" height="25" x="0" y="60" fill="#fff">
        You can click to edit (and click outside
    </text>
    <text width="325" height="25" x="0" y="85" fill="#fff">
        the box when done). Chrome only :-(
    </text>
</svg>
```

Ultimately I want this in an SVG file that's included in an HTML file (using <object>). To emulate this, I've saved the code above in an SVG file and look at it on my own machine via a localhost URL.

Curiously if I put it in a codepen (paste the SVG above as HTML), it works fine in Firefox. But then that's really because the SVG is in-lined into HTML, which I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a trick to get Firefox working. And is there a trick to get IE working too?

Comment: Firefox insists on the document being an HTML document. You could always try raising a bug in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG)

Comment: I have, but you beat me to it @RobertLongson :-)